# Can I call anonymous function from ExternalInterface.call() method?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to get a javascript var in my Flash application. I like to be able to just set a variable in the javascript (client constraints) rather than define a function.

Can this be done? I am trying to use the ExternalInterface.call()

AS:

`ExternalInterface.call("function(){return window.someVar}", null)`;

JS:

```
var someVar = "Test";
```

This does not work and I suspect it is because the ExternalInterface.call() does not like the anonymous function. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oops. Forgot the ';'

It works. Thanks anyways all.

```
ExternalInterface.call("function(){return window.someVar;}", null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it still work without the ; ?

You also don't need to pass null by the way. But I think a better way to do it is

```
ExternalInterface.call("(function(){return window.someVar}()", null)
```

Note the **()** make its get called.

I don't have Flash right now to test it though. Let me know if it doesn't work